# What are the rainy "giant owl" room's secrets?

Tags: fez

Off of the dark, rainy node, the one with the owl's head that follows you. The map marks a secret on this node, and a grayed-out child node. Are they two different secrets?

[image: giant owl node]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two "secrets": **the four owl puzzle** (denoted by a question mark on the node), and **the subsequent anticube room**.

### Four owls

In four places, an owl appears at night. Speak with each one:

1. **in the waterfall level near the pillar** (green tree, first warp zone), [image: waterfall owl]
2. **in the windmill level near the windmill** (orange tree, air warp zone), [image: windmill owl]
3. **in the forest near the transforming cabin** (green tree, outside rainy warp zone), [image: forest owl]
4. and **outside the octopus-looking building containing the revolving model of the solar system and the counting cube** (pink tree, temple/science warp zone). [image: science owl]

These locations were shown on the walls of the fez-wearing elder's house (in Gomez's hometown, across the bridge).

### Hidden room

After speaking with each owl, they fly to the rainy warp zone's giant owl room. When all four arrive, a panel reveals a door behind the owl statue opposite the entrance. It leads to another owl room with an anticube.

[image: door to second owl room]

> **Glitch**: If you *remove the patch*, the original version of the game had a glitch where you could access the hidden room without the four owls: stand in front of the entrance, rotate the room twice, and press up to enter. Keep in mind, the room won't be "completed" until the main secret (four owls) is finished and the next room is visited.

Comment: I am now in the Octopus room, but there is no owl. Why?

Comment: @wil: Wait for nightfall

Answer (score 4):

I just got it by accident. Stand in front of the door below the owl but don't press up. Now, Spin the screen so you're standing BEHIND the owl. Now press up to go through the door even though the door isn't facing the screen. Hope that helps.

Comment: Probably a bug or glitch that's been fixed. It doesn't work on the PS3/PS4/PSV version.

Answer (score 4):

There are four live owls within other nodes that you need to talk to in order to open this door. You can find clues to their locations in the village in the house of the guy with the eye patch. I think they only appear at night.