# What's the secret of the secondary owl room off of the water tower room?

Tags: fez

[image]

This owl room is in the air warp zone, not the rainy warp zone, off of the water tower node. What is its secret?

[image]

That owl doesn't rotate its head when switching the perspective.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/what-are-the-secrets-on-the-giant-owl-room-in-the-rainy-warp-zone

Comment: No, it's another room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This room is an alternative to the ["blank map" QR puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62444/21177) for those without QR readers.** They both result in the same [tetromino code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177), but if you do one, the other will count as "completed". Thus, this puzzle is *optional*. (The difference: the code has to be entered as if it was found in this room unless you have the blank map.)

The [tetromino code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) is shown in two places in this room: in the S- and Z-blocks around the tower's base (loop once), and as the fezzes atop the alien drawings at the owl's feet (only visible in first-person mode).

**The code:**

> RT RT RT LT RT RT RT LT

[image: owl room S-block]
[image: owl room Z-block]
[image: aliens with tetromino hats]
[image: owl room anticube]

Comment: I don't understand where is the tetramino code you refer too. Could you please for example circle it on the screenshots?

Comment: @wil: On the third screenshot, look at the tetrominos floating above the white rectangular heads on the ground. Together, they form a code and it's the same as the one on the "blank" map linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I found it !

Use the first person view to look at the floor, where stands the owl.

There are characters with fezzes indicating LT and RT.

Solution :

> RT RT RT LT RT RT RT LT