# Why won't the blank map QR code map work?

Tags: fez

I scanned the QR code on the back of the blank map and came up with `RT RT RT LT RT RT RT LT`

I entered it and nothing happened.  Is there another puzzle that cancels it out, or is my game just glitched?

Comment: Is there any possibility that you already did that somewhere and got the anti cube that goes with it?

Comment: i tryed it and *worked just fine* for me

Answer (score 4):

**The [secondary owl puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62782/21177) off of the water tower cancels out the blank map QR puzzle.** (They have the same code, but you can only get one anticube from the two.)