# Are some puzzles/secrets temporarily unsolvable?

Tags: fez

I'm playing Fez with my wife, and we're really enjoying the secrets.  I'd like to finish it, or as much as I can bear, without using a guide or anything to solve the puzzles.  The one thing I'd like to know is: are some puzzles temporarily unsolvable?  What I mean is, when I encounter a puzzle, do I automatically have everything I need to solve it, or could I be lacking an in game item or ability that makes it possible to solve.  I don't want examples, I just want to know if there are puzzles I might encounter that can't be solved till I play further in the game.  That way I can stop banging my head against the wall (temporarily).

Thus far, I've yet to encounter a puzzle that couldn't be solved on the spot - but I theorize there are some abilities or something that I'll get later that make other puzzles solvable that are not yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

Some puzzles require [interactions in](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62374/21177) or [knowledge from](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62812/21177) other rooms first. [Some](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62428/21177) require beating the game once (to get a new feature in New Game+ mode). [Some](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62515/21177) require checking the Internet since there are no in-game clues.

Comment: I just want to follow up to say thanks.  I doubted you at first, but having finished the game I see now that one puzzle was ***completely unsolvable*** without the internet.  Lame.  For the benefit of others, I'll also add that controller vibration is a key (if you turn that off by default like I do).